# MDX, Remove Zero-Rows On ROWS

Tags: mdx

My MDX-Query looks like this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2014_1-12] AS 
  ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[ACTUAL]), 
MEMBER [YEAR].[P2014_1-12] AS 
  ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[PLAN]),                           
MEMBER [YEAR].[P2015_1-12] AS 
  ([YEAR].[2015], [TYPE].[PLAN]),                          
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2015_YTD] AS 
  SUM(
    {[YEARPERIOD].[201501]:[YEARPERIOD].[201509]}
    ,(
     [Measures].currentmember
    ,[TYPE].[ACTUAL]
     )
   )                                           
SELECT 
{
[YEAR].[A2014_1-12],
[YEAR].[P2014_1-12],
[YEAR].[P2015_1-12],
[YEAR].[A2015_YTD]
}             
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
 [COST_CENTER]
 *[COST_ELEMENT] ON ROWS 
FROM [CUBE] 
WHERE ([Measures].[COSTS]);
```

The Query itself is working. However it is also returning a lot of zero-rows and I would like to get rid of these zero-rows. The strange thing is - If I put only one MEMBER (e.g. [YEAR].[A2014_1-12]) on the COLUMNS-axis it is not returning any zero-rows. But as soon as I start to add another MEMBER to the COLUMN-axis it is also many returning zero-rows (It seems like it is ignoring the NON EMPTY in my CROSSJOIN). How can I remove the zero-rows in the above MDX-Query?

Comment: I suspect they are not empty but are 0 - `Non Empty` and `NonEmpty `will only ignore empty cube space but if there is a zero in the cube space then these functions will not exclude the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a start

```
WITH 
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2014_1-12] AS 
  iif(
    ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[ACTUAL]) = 0
    ,null
    ,([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[ACTUAL])
  )
MEMBER [YEAR].[P2014_1-12] AS 
  iif(
    ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[PLAN]) = 0 
    ,null
    ,([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[PLAN])
  )                                                    
SELECT 
NON EMPTY
{
[YEAR].[A2014_1-12],
[YEAR].[P2014_1-12]
}             
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
 [COST_CENTER]
 *[COST_ELEMENT] ON ROWS 
FROM [CUBE] 
WHERE ([Measures].[COSTS]);
```

As an aside you do not need to define the current member of the measures hierarchy in this definition:

```
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2015_YTD] AS 
  SUM(
    {[YEARPERIOD].[201501]:[YEARPERIOD].[201509]}
    ,(
     [Measures].currentmember
    ,[TYPE].[ACTUAL]
     )
   )
```

This is enough:

```
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2015_YTD] AS 
  SUM(
    {[YEARPERIOD].[201501]:[YEARPERIOD].[201509]}
    ,([TYPE].[ACTUAL])
   )
```

Try this instead:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [YEAR].[A2014_1-12] AS 
  iif(
    ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[ACTUAL]) = 0
    ,null
    ,([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[ACTUAL])
  )
MEMBER [YEAR].[P2014_1-12] AS 
  iif(
    ([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[PLAN]) = 0 
    ,null
    ,([YEAR].[2014], [TYPE].[PLAN])
  ) 
SET [X] AS
 NonEmtpy(
  [COST_CENTER]*[COST_ELEMENT],
  {[YEAR].[A2014_1-12],[YEAR].[P2014_1-12]}
)                                                   
SELECT 
NON EMPTY
{
[YEAR].[A2014_1-12],
[YEAR].[P2014_1-12]
}             
ON 0,
//NON EMPTY 
 [X] ON 1
FROM [CUBE] 
WHERE ([Measures].[COSTS]);
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for your suggestions. I removed Currentmember and the query still works as desired :-). I also added the IIF-Clause to the WITH-MEMBER statements but still the EMPTY rows show up again as soon as I add more than MEMBER on the columns-axis. It seems like system interprets NON EMPTY on ROWS-axis correct with one member on the column axis. As soon as I add 2nd (or 3rd, 4th) member on the column axis system seems to ignore NON EMPTY on the ROWS axis and shows all possible combinations of Cost_Center * Cost_Element on the rows-axis. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: Hello, again many thanks for your suggestions. I added SET [X] AS
 NonEmtpy(...statement to the MDX-Query. However I get an error as result (runtime error - an exception has occured). If I remove NonEmpty from SET [X] AS ... (...) statement I get error message: Invalid MDX command with crossjoin (<set>, <set>). In the next few days I will experiment a little bit more with the ideas suggested by you. If everything fails I will simply write a VBA-Code to delete the empty rows from the result that the MDX-Query returns. Again many thanks for your suggestions. JDB